# Djagno and ElasticSearch how to allow search with typos

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to elastic search and I want to enable searching with typos (max of 2 letters).

**example**

```
input: gpple
result: google
/////////////
input: convarsetyon (3 letters typos, meant to be : conversation )
result: none
```

my backend is Django and the way i communicate with elastic search is via elasticsearch-dsl
I tried to implement add fuzziness attribute to the wildcard query but it resulted in an error

**views.py**:

```
class SearchRecipes(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecipeSearchSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        word = self.kwargs['word']
        
        recipeQueryset = RecipeDocument.search().query('wildcard',title=f'*{word}*').sort("-score")

        return recipeQueryset
```

**documents.py**

```
autocomplete_analyzer = analyzer('autocomplete_analyzer',
            tokenizer=tokenizer('trigram', 'edge_ngram', min_gram=1, max_gram=20),
            filter=['lowercase']
        )

@registry.register_document
class RecipeDocument(Document):
    title = fields.TextField(required=True, analyzer=autocomplete_analyzer)
    class Index:
        name = 'recipes'
        settings = {
        'number_of_shards': 1,
        'number_of_replicas': 0,
        'max_ngram_diff': 20
        }

    class Django:
        model = Recipe
        fields = [
            'score',
        ]
```

Anyone have a clue how to do this?  thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use n_grams with something like `search_as_you_type` field ?

Comment: not at all, how can I implement it?